# Javascript console errors and WSOD on edit post pages

Tags: plugins, themes, block-editor

We have been running into a weird issue where we get WSOD on post pages with bunch of react errors. This only happens after sometime  a deployment is done. When the page breaks, we rollback to a older version and redeploy the existing version. The site become stable after that until it breaks after sometime (usually a day). We use docker containers (WP 5.7.0) and K8s for container orchestration. We have tried everything that we can find in the internet such as Turning off All plugins, Using Default Themes, etc. We don't have any caching.  After that we've tried installing Classic Editor plugin activating it and the frequency of error has decreased so it seems like the issue is coming from Gutenberg editor. We have exhausted every other possible options.

These are some example of error messages we get :

```
TypeError: r is not a function
    at https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/components.min.js?ver=863b0e64189bf5cd6b5aced6797bc2d6:7:309054
    at Bh (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:126:456)
    at Dj (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:162:476)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=16.13.1:25:260)
    at Da (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:60:280)
    at xb (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:162:231)
    at mk.Events.current (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:236:102)
    at Ei (https://ourcompany.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:41:59)


Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'languageProcessing')

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'helpers')

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.yoast.editorModules.analysis')

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.SETTINGS_DEFAULTS')

The block "core/paragraph" must have a title.

The block "core/image" must have a title.

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. The above error occurred in the <Context.Provider> component:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Layout`.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')
```

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without some error messages to go on.

Comment: I'd guess either some scripts aren't loading, which ought to be visible in the console, or are getting returned empty. Can you find anything like that? You'd then need to work out if the request is making it to WordPress or not, and whether WordPress still has the correct file to serve. It might be easiest to debug if you set the define to return non-minified scripts too.

Comment: Not 100% about the fix we did, but we saw couple of PHP files we had created had closing tags ?>, after removing those the errors seemed to go away